# Is there an app to sync two android devices over Bluetooth ? (like Syncthing or Resillo, but over Bluetooth)

Tags: android, file-management, file-synchronization, wifi, bluetooth

Is there an app that can sync folders and files in two android devices ?

The devices are physically nearby, but not connected to the same Wi-Fi network. They are connected to the internet using their respective mobile data connection. Is there an app that can sync files between them using Bluetooth and maybe use Wi-Fi Direct when large data transfer is needed ?

I don't want AirDrop or NearbyShare like functionality. I want Resillo or Syncthing functionality over Bluetooth.